# How to use dates in PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I've been playing with PHP/MySQL date formats and decided to use varchar for Data Type as this seems easier and no processing will be required.

I found some code which is described below...

```
mysql> describe dateplayground;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| dp_name | varchar(100) | NO   |     |         |       |
| dp_date | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

With this PHP..

```
$query = "INSERT INTO dateplayground (dp_name, dp_date) VALUES ('DATE: ', '2015-12-31')";
```

the result is..

```
+---------+------------+
| dp_name | dp_date    |
+---------+------------+
| DATE:   | 2015-12-31 |
+---------+------------+
```

If I change date constant to variable as in..

```
$dd = '2015-12-31';
$query = "INSERT INTO dateplayground (dp_name, dp_date) VALUES ('DATE: ', $dd)";
```

the result is..

```
+---------+------------+
| dp_name | dp_date    |
+---------+------------+
| DATE:   | 2015-12-31 |
| DATE:   | 1972       |
+---------+------------+
```

So the MySQL variable (dp_date), whose type is varchar(64) gets the string '2015-12-31', and does a subtraction with it !!!!!!!

Also if the variable contains chars as in..

```
$dd = 'fred';
```

The call does not INSERT a new row !!!!

Any suggestions as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: why dont you use 'dp_date' type to "date" ?

Comment: You should use 'dp_date' data type as date.

Comment: unquote your date placeholder in the query, just DATE: not 'DATE:'

Comment: Your mistake is trying to treat dates as strings. You should use proper date/time types for dates. Doing otherwise will come back and bite you sooner or later.

Comment: @HoboSapiens That is not the actual mistake in this question.

Comment: @loko maybe not, but the OP's approach is fundamentally flawed. His next question is likely to involve date arithmetic...

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the date value going to the db.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO dateplayground (dp_name, dp_date) VALUES ('DATE: ', '$dd')"
```

Comment: @Loko, ah I see what you mean. Missed that it wasn't a date column.